# Blurred lines between health SE and Fitness SE

Tags: discussion

Looking at the site stats of the two sites, fitness needs a lot more work than health to become a healthy beta. Why don't we merge the sites when health has a lot of fitness themed questions and vice versa already?

Comment: I'd suggest reading through some old, old meta questions about this. We had a lot of discussion about what our scope included. Originally we were "Fitness & Nutrition" but the site started trending towards questions related to medical issues which wasn't in our scope. Eventually the "Nutrition" portion was dropped to reflect the niche focus of what the site was becoming.

Comment: http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/117/where-does-fitness-stop-and-general-health-start

http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/135/are-ergonomics-on-topic-for-fitness

http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/86/should-the-scope-be-expanded-to-fitness-sports

The term "fitness" was a little too loose and open for interpretation. We had scope issues for a long time and also had to battle out whether sports as a whole was considered on topic or not.

Comment: Here's the official word on the change from "Fitness & Nutrition" to "Physical Fitness." http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/287/should-title-be-fitness-instead-of-fitness-and-nutrition/295#295

Comment: @MattChan hmm, ok. But if this site and the Health site eventually both fail (or even if one fails) would you be up for a merge? I don't know much (obviously) about stackexchange betas, but I once proposed an origami proposal and it got merged with arts and crafts.

Comment: That choice is up to the community here and on Health.SE as a whole and whatever input the Community Team at Stack Exchange has. It really depends.

Comment: Also, Health.SE is not a "healthy" beta. This beta is much more robust and established. I am a mod on health, and the quality of questions is banal at best. There has even been talk from some of the more established users that the site is not really viable.

Comment: Also, under the changes a year or so ago, betas don't close like they used to. This one has an established user base, flags are handled and we keep the peace. It's in no danger of closing.

Comment: @JohnP thanks. Will the people in charge eventually redirect health SE users to PF?

Comment: Not likely. They are specifically off topic here. And the PTB don't really set site scope, that is more a community decision.